# How to loop threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I know in java you can create an array or list(honestly I forget which one) that you  can store a series of classes. I want to be able to have a program that has one of those lists and will loop through each class and run a certain method in each class(yes all the classes extend one abstract class) in a new thread. Is this possible? I am very sorry if I am not describing my problem well if some people comment and say I need to describe it better I will attempt to.

Comment: What does this question have to do with threads?

Comment: probably the bit where he says "in a new thread" ...

Comment: Ah, my eyes glazed over that bit. Must be late. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(tweaking StriplingWarrior's example class names here to show how to thread it)

To run in a thread your classes need to `implement Runnable`, i.e. contain the method `public void run()`, thus:

```
public abstract class Foo implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       bar();
    }
    public void bar();  // the method that'll be overridden
}
```

Then, for each element in your list:

```
List<Foo> foos;
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    new Thread(foo).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ThreadPoolExeuctor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and feed it a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)< Runable>.